# REDHAWK RAP support?

Tags: redhawksdr

I've been using the Explorer/IDE lately on my local machine; however, I'd like to be able to run everything (including custom control panels, if possible) using a web-browser (as I understand, REDHAWK supports RAP).  I've tried running it like any other RAP application, but it complains about not having an equinox console: "Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console"

It would be preferable to run headlessly, but can be done via Eclipse if need be.

Answer (score 0):

To run the REDHAWK Sca Explorer as a RAP application, you have to create a target that includes:

1. The plug-ins included in the RAP 1.5 target platform components provided by the eclipse foundation. Be sure the following plug-ins are included, which are needed to run the OSGI console when the RAP application is launched:

   org.eclipse.equinox.console

   org.apache.felix.gogo.command

   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime

   org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
2. The resolvable plugins from the REDHAWK gov.redhawk.core repo. You'll have to manually exclude plug-ins whose dependencies can't be resolved using the RAP target platform components from item 1.
3. The plugin from the REDHAWK gov.redhawk.explorer.rap.product repo.